# Local server (Ubuntu) reachable by name (ubuntu or ubuntu.local) only by wired devices

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I have this home server running Ubuntu that is only reachable by name (ubuntu or ubuntu.local) by the wired devices in my home network.
The devices connected to the same network, through the wifi of the only router in the network, can't reach the server by its name, only by its ip.
I read about it and someone suggested installing avahi-daemon. I did, but it didn't change this behaviour.
Is there another solution I could try?

My network is in the 10.0.0.X range.

My server has this local network config:

```
inet 10.0.0.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

My smartphone, for example, is:

```
10.0.0.102 - mask 255.255.255.0
```

When he tries to access "ubuntu:port" or "ubuntu.local:port" on the browser he receives a DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Thanks!

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the IP and subnet of both your server and the wired and wireless clients? From an IP perspective your server shouldn't care, so probably something else is going on.

Comment: Hello there, I added the info, thanks.

Comment: What about non-phone WiFi devices? Perhaps they use DNS over HTTP, or perhaps directly nameservers like Google's 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Hello, I tried on a tablet. It's a differente error: "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED".

Comment: Ha, tabls didn't register on my radar. I meant a traditional laptop, Windows, Mac or Linux.

Comment: Hello, I tried on a Laptop and indeed it reached the server through "ubuntu". Looks like only smartphones and tablets can't reach it. It's all DHCP here and the gateway has sends the same and specific DNS to all devices.

Comment: As I said, I suspect those Android devices use DNS provided by Google directly.